# How to select a value from dropdown in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

Sorry if the question has been asked before. But I am just starting with programming and Selenium.: I need help with selecting a value from the below drop down:
[image]

Below is the HTML Code 
[image]

I tried to select Delhi by using its xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//a[@text='Delhi (DEL)'][contains(text(),'Delhi (DEL)')]")).click();
```

The error I got in console is:

> "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//a[@text='Delhi (DEL)'][contains(text(),'Delhi (DEL)')]"}"

Can you please help me, what is the other way to select a value from this dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='dropdownGroup1']//div[@class='dropdownDiv']//ul//li//a[@text='Delhi (DEL)']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//a[@text='Goa (GOI)'][contains(text(),'Goa (GOI)')]"))).click()
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: @Sino: please verify above solution from your end